# JS - play different sound after each click

Tags: javascript, html, audio, onclick

I have a single link and I want the link to play different sounds each time it is clicked. When I click the link it plays both sounds at the same time but I want one sound at a time

```
var bleep = new Audio('hello.mp3') ;
bleep.src = "hello.mp3" ; 

var bleep2 = new Audio('goodbye.mp3') ;
bleep2.src = "goodbye.mp3"; 



    <a href="#" onclick="bleep.play('hello.mp3'); bleep2.play('goodbye.mp3');">Home</a>
```

Comment: What determines which sound is played when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make a function out of it that checks which sound was clicked last time. Also, you neither need to set the `.src` property or pass a string to [the play method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play).

**JS:**

```
var bleep = new Audio('hello.mp3');

var bleep2 = new Audio('goodbye.mp3');

var playFirst = true;
function playSound() {
  if (playFirst) {
    bleep.play();
  } else {
    bleep2.play();
  }
  playFirst = !playFirst;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" onclick="playSound()">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of attaching the event listener inline as `onclick`, attach it with JS using `addEventListener`. This allows you to pick which audio clip to play:

```
var helloSound = new Audio('hello.mp3');
helloSound.src = "hello.mp3"; 

var goodbyeSound = new Audio('goodbye.mp3');
goodbyeSound.src = "goodbye.mp3";

var homeLink = document.getElementById('home-link');

homeLink.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (/* condition to play hello */) {
        helloSound.play();
    } else {
        goodbyeSound.play();
    }
});
```

Markup:

```
<a href="#" id="home-link">Home</a>
```